# Automatically add simple custom buttons for print, Facebook share, & Tweet in Posts

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-sharing

I want an easy way to **automatically** implement **printing**, **Facebook sharing**, and **Tweeting** for **posts**. **No plugins, complicated javascript, nor functions.**

Comment: Can you add more details about the issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm not facing an issue. I'm presenting a potential solution to help others... I would answer my own question, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Natan [Everyone can answer the own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). You just have to wait a little bit longer.

Comment: Whoops. My mistake. #_#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the built in Facebook sharer and Twitter sharer links, as provided on each site. It won't give complete functionality, but it it's perfect for a simple custom icon.

**Note**: This will only work properly within 'the loop'

HTML code to be inserted in your page template:

```
<div class="social_icons">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" target="_blank" class="printIcon">
       Print page
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" class="facebookIcon">
       Share on Facebook
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>+&ndash;+" target="_blank" class="twitterIcon">
       Tweet on Twitter
    </a>
</div>
```

Basic CSS styling:

```
.social_icons {
    float: right; /*change for your specific needs*/
}

.social_icons a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 50px; /*change for your specific needs*/
    display: block;
    float: right; /*change for your specific needs*/
}

.social_icons a.printIcon {
    background-image: url(); /*add a custom share icon*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.social_icons a.facebookIcon {
    background-image: url(); /*add a custom share icon*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.social_icons a.twitterIcon {
    background-image: url(); /*add a custom share icon*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```